# Console output of Eclipse with timestamp

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium, log4j

I am using Eclipse for my selenium webdriver scripts.Is there any settings/tools/plugins/process so that i can see console output with timestamps.
I am using application log using log4j framework.But there is a requirement from my client that they need console output with timestamps.I have thought of using printing of time before every command,but its not an effective way of doing so.

Thanks,
Manash

Comment: Have you already a configuration for your loggers/appenders?

Comment: Yes.I am using log4j for logging into application log.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
 log4j.appender.ConsoleAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=[%-5p] %d %c - %m%n
```

You have info on the ConversionPattern's printing performance here: http://www.codejava.net/coding/common-conversion-patterns-for-log4js-patternlayout

Comment: I am already using log4j for logging.I need to see timestamps in Console output.

Comment: Yeah, but in order to get log4j timestamps you must use a conversion pattern. Did you try the line of code I wrote above? 

You can write to the console from log4j, please read [link](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-log4j-properties-examples/)

Comment: Thanks Veronica,Its working fine after editing the properties of log4j.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this answer will be valid, unfamiliar with selenium and I dislike log4j (so I will give an answer that works without it).

The documentation for [System](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) can be useful, particularly [setErr](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setErr%28java.io.PrintStream%29) and [setOut](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#setOut%28java.io.PrintStream%29). You can change the output streams to streams that attach the timestamp before directing the given string to the console. Or instead of doing System.setOut & System.setErr you write a class ABC with public static [printstreams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html) like System. When you call the ABC.out.print or ABC.err.print methods, the class adds the timestamp then directs it to System.out & System.err respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try the below code. The below code is working fine for me.

```
log4j.rootLogger=debug, stdout, R

log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout

# Pattern to output the caller's file name and line number.
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}:

log4j.appender.R=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.R.File=applicationlog path

log4j.appender.R.MaxFileSize=100KB
# Keep one backup file
log4j.appender.R.MaxBackupIndex=1

log4j.appender.R.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.R.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss}:
```

Thanks,

Sudhansu, Mindfiresolutions
http://www.mindfiresolutions.com/

Comment: Thanks Sudhansu
This code is working fine.I am able to see timestamps in console.